# Loop through array on button click with math random

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, loops

I'm having a problem with a loop that I want the array to feed the src of an iframe in a fiddle. I want the loop to iterate through the array on the same button push until it reaches the end of the loop.

Here is the code that I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jgbutton" class="demo">
    <button>Push me, Lara</button>
    <p>(and again, till you like what you see)</p>
</div>
<div class="datecontentwrapper">
    <iframe src="" id="iframeFILL"></iframe>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery("#jgbutton").click(function () {
var dateplaces = ["http://www.tate.org.uk/whats-on/tate-modern/exhibition/henri-matisse-cut-outs", "http://www.bootstrapcompany.co.uk/22_dalston_roof_park", "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Light_Painting_1_-_Booyeembara_Park.jpg", "http://www.happinessforgets.com/", "http://www.gordonswinebar.com/defaultm.php"];
        var arrayLength = dateplaces.length;
        var genrandomdate = dateplaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * dateplaces.length)];

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            $("#iframeFILL").attr("src", dateplaces[i]);
            $(".datecontentwrapper").show('slow');
            $("p").show();
        }

});
```

**JSfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/8Gnuy/9/

Am I declaring the variables globally, instead of within the for loop, perhaps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question

Comment: The code is working, please elaborate the problem.

Comment: Do you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gnuy/13/ ???

Comment: Perfect @A.Wolff - that's the stuff!

Comment: Have adapted slightly to confirm finish: http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/8Gnuy/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need loop for?
Just remove it and it will do what you expected to do.

Instead of loop call random element on every button click:

```
 $("#iframeFILL").attr("src", genrandomdate);
    $(".datecontentwrapper").show('slow');
    $("p").show();
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Gnuy/11/)

If you want to loop (not random) through links, use this:

```
    var currentIndex = $("#iframeFILL").data('index');
    if (!currentIndex || currentIndex>arrayLength) {
        fill(1);
    } else {
        fill(currentIndex);
    }

    function fill(i) {            
        $("#iframeFILL").attr("src", dateplaces[i-1]).data('index', i+1);
        $(".datecontentwrapper").show('slow');
        $("p").show();
    }
```

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Gnuy/15/)

Comment: Not quite because if it is random, it can duplicate an array entry.

Comment: see updated answer. you can either use random link or next one, but you can't use both :)